# Generate and Export RSA Key Pair on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rsa

I'm attempting to generate a KeyPair on Android and export the Public Key as a String so it's in the format -

`-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----MIIB...`

I've used the following to successfully generate the KeyPair -

```
fun generateKeyPair(): KeyPair {
    val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)

    generator.initialize(2048, SecureRandom())
    val keypair = generator.genKeyPair()
    return keypair
}

val keypair = generateKeyPair()

Log.d("Keypair", keypair.public.toString())
```

But this gives me -

```
OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=e0a6a5a...
```

Does anyone know how I can export the key in the aforementioned format?

Comment: https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES

Comment: No Android method will give you the key in the format you want. You'll either have to do a lot work yourself or use a library like Bouncycastle/Spongycastle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this the answer is -

```
val keyText = Base64.encodeToString(keypair.public.encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: on android use Base64.NO_WRAP to omit all line terminators (the output will be on one long line)